# Default.png not showing in RELEASE mode on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I've got an openGL ES application up and running on the iPhone.

And my project has a Default.png to show something other than a black screen on powerup.

This image appears when I compile a DEBUG version for the simulator and the device.  If I do a compile for the DEVICE in RELEASE mode, the image does not show up (black screen instead).

I'm running OS3.0 Beta 5.

Comment: Are there differences in your main .plist file between the two release profiles?

Comment: Ummm, Not that I'm aware of.  I'm a bit of a newb when it comes to all of this Xcode stuff.  How would I check that?  I just have one Info.plist as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.  it was named default.png and not Default.png.  Case MATTTERS!

I also had to do a clean build of all targets,